# parsing the output of the 'w' command?

Tags: c, parsing, command-line

I'm writing a program which requires knowledge of the current load on the system, and the activity of any users (it's a load balancer).

This is a university assignment, and I am required to use the `w` command. I'm having a hard time parsing this command because it is very verbose. Any suggestions on what I can do would be appreciated. This is a small part of the program, and I am free to use whatever method i like.

The most condensed version of w which still has the information I require is `w -u -s -f' which produces this:

```
 10:13:43 up  9:57,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
 USER     TTY         IDLE WHAT
 fsm      tty7      22:44m x-session-manager
 fsm      pts/0      0.00s w -u -s -f
```

So out of that, I am interested in the first number after load average and the smallest idle time (so i will need to parse them all).

My background process will call w, so the fact that w is the lowest idle time will not matter (all i will see is the tty time).

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

(I am allowed to use alternative unix commands, like grep, if that helps).

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use other Unix commands? You could use `grep`, `sed` or `head`/`tail` to get the lines you need, and `cut` to split them up as needed.

Comment: I can, sure. Could you give an example though?

Answer (score 0):

- Check out: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regexp-Subexpressions.html#Regexp-Subexpressions
- Use regular expressions to match `[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}` on the first line. You may have to fiddle with which characters are escaped. That will give you 3 load averages.
- The remaining output is column-based, so if you count off the string positions from w, you'll be able to just strncpy the interesting bits.

Another possible theory (which sounds like it goes against the assignment, but I'd keep it in mind) is to go grab the source code of w and hack it up to just tell you the information via function calls. If you're feeling really hardcore, you can learn all the library api calls and do it directly that way.

Answer (score 0):

I found i can use a combination of commands like so:

w -u -s -f | grep load | cut -d " " -f 11

and

w -u -s -f | grep tty | cut -d " " -f 13

the first takes the output of w, uses grep to only select the line with load, and then cuts everything except for the 11th chunk of data (delimiter is a space), which is the first load number with a comma.

the second does something similar, only for user load. And if there are multiple loads, its a list.

This is easy enough to parse, unless someone has an objection, or suggestion to improve it.